# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (848,837,8) into shape (800,800,8)

Tags: python, deep-learning, valueerror

When I run the code in kaggle kernel, it is working fine, but when executing the code on my machine, it throws this error. please help

Comment: It would be next to impossible to help you without seeing the code throwing the error. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before fixing your question accordingly.

Comment: add the code please

Answer (score 0):

so in my case, I was running the code in python 2.7 in which Python 2.7 will give different ceil value as the answer, Python 3.4 reports different value.